# Dudas sobre código de javascript

Tags: javascript

He visto en internet sobre éste código y no logro entender bien del todo de lo que sucede tras esto, veo que separa los valores de la clave `modo` y los muestra en un nuevo objeto, pero no entiendo porqué sucede esto.

```js
let obj = {modo: "COM"}
console.log({...obj.modo})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

****[Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)****

> La sintaxis spread (...) permite expandir un elemento iterable, como
> una matriz o una cadena, en lugares donde se esperan cero o más
> argumentos (para llamadas a funciones) o elementos (para literales de
> matriz). En un literal de objeto, la sintaxis de propagación enumera
> las propiedades de un objeto y agrega los pares clave-valor al objeto
> que se está creando.

Con `...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Distribuye los elementos dentro de un iterable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto que no era iterable ahora iterado con un `for in`

```js
    let obj = {modo: "COM"}
    let iterable = {...obj.modo}
    
    for (const property in iterable) {
      console.log(`${property}: ${iterable[property]}`);
    }
```

Sin `...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Spread Operator** puede utilizarse cuando todos los elementos de un objeto o matriz deben incluirse en una ***nueva matriz u objeto***, o deben aplicarse uno por uno en la lista de argumentos de una llamada a función.

**[Otro usos](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/spread-operator)**

***Copiar arreglo mediante*** `...`

> También puede utilizar la sintaxis de propagación para copiar los
> elementos en una sola matriz. Por ejemplo...

```
const arr1 = ['one', 'two'];
const arr2 = [...arr1, 'three', 'four', 'five'];

console.log(arr2); 
//  Output:
//  ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

**Clonar matriz usando el operador Spread**

En JavaScript, los objetos se asignan por referencia y no por valores. Por ejemplo

Aquí ambas variables se refieren a la misma matriz

```
let arr1 = [ 1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = arr1;

console.log(arr1); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr2); // [1, 2, 3]

// append an item to the array
arr1.push(4);

console.log(arr1); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(arr2); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> Si quieres copiar matrices para que no hagan referencia a
> la misma matriz, puede utilizar el operador de propagación. De esta
> manera, el cambio en una matriz no se refleja en la otra. Por ejemplo

```
let arr1 = [ 1, 2, 3];

// copy using spread syntax
let arr2 = [...arr1];

console.log(arr1); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr2); // [1, 2, 3]

// append an item to the array
arr1.push(4);

console.log(arr1); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(arr2); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, alfin me quedo claro jaja

Answer (score 1):

EL código hace uso del Spread Operator (...) segun la documentacion de [MDN Web Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> 'Permite a un elemento iterable tal como un arreglo o cadena ser
> expandido en lugares donde cero o más argumentos (para llamadas de
> función) o elementos (para Array literales) son esperados, o a un
> objeto ser expandido en lugares donde cero o más pares de valores
> clave (para literales Tipo Objeto) son esperados'.

En tu caso estás utilizando spread sobre el valor de una sola propiedad y lo colocas como contenido de un objeto nuevo. Si usas Spread (desparramar, separar) de esa forma crearas un objeto con pares clave valor de la forma 'numero: letra', ese número será 0 para la primera propiedad, 1 para la segunda etc como si fueran los índices de un arreglo, y las letras de tu propiedad 'modo' serían los valores para esas claves, por lo que tendrías un objeto nuevo con 4 propiedades y las letras de 'modo' como sus valores.

Distinto seria si hicieses eso pero con un array:

```js
let obj = {modo: "COM", interconectado: "WWW"}
console.log([...obj.interconectado]) // output: ["W","W","W"]
```

En este caso las claves numéricas ya no son necesarias porque los arrays ya cuentan con índices. Ya te dieron una buena respuesta así que dejo mi explicación aqui jeje.